# Updating "support" or "range" in transformation variable

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

I submitted the final in a theoretical stats class and had trouble with several problems, but part of one is bugging me because it seems like it should be simple.  Lets say we have two random independent variables $X$ and $Y$, each with their respective pdf $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.  The support for each is:
$-\infty < X < \infty$, and $-\infty < Y < \infty$.

How do I determine what the support should be for a transformation to a new random variable $Z$, that utilizes both $X$ and $Y$?

Several examples might be:

1. $Z = X-Y$
2. $Z = X\times Y$
3. $Z = X/Y$

What is the range of $Z$?

- $-\infty < Z < \infty$ ?
- $0 < Z < \infty$ ?

I think the lower bound would be 0 for case #2, but how can you determine this for 1, 2, and/or 3 given above?

I have Casella and Berger's (2002) *Statistical Inference* text for the class, but I don't understand how to "update the support" from this book.  I've had virtually 0 luck Googling this.

Thanks for any suggestions either directly explaining how, or for a source.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think the lower bound must be $0$ for $X \times Y$?  You stipulated independence, so it seems to me possible that $X$ and $Y$ could have opposite signs, leading to negative values of $Z$.

Comment: One way to think about this is to imagine a tiny interval around $Z=z$ and see if there is a positive probability of it happening.  In these cases this translates to given $Z=z$ do there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $z = x \text{ (op) } y$?.

Comment: deinst: thank you, I will try to think through some examples using what you've said.  I've tried to find some examples with answers, because I hate simply assuming I am guessing correctly.